# Парсинг, проблема с соеденением интернета

Tags: python, парсер

Уважаемые программисты! Суть вопроса вот в чем, имеется парсер который ежедневно запускается в 07-00, парсит инфу, но в один прекрасный день, с 06-50 до 07-10 пропало соединенние с интернетом, в результате чего, естественно парсинг в этот день не запустился. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить эту проблему, может прописать какое то условие в цикле, или исключение? Подскажите пожалуйста.
Заранее очень Вам благодарен!

Comment: Нет он конечно запустился, но выдал ошибку: equests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.livesport.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /tips/football/2022/02/09/milan_lazio/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000242119E09D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')). Вот я и спашиваю как обойти эту ошибку. Как написать условия или цикл!

Comment: Отловить ошибку конструкцией try-except и всё это завернуть в цикл

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать как-то так:

```
import requests
import time

# ваши функции, переменные и т.п.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            parse() # попытка спарсить.
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print('No internet. Trying again...')
            time.sleep(5*60) # ждем 5 минут и потом пробуем снова спарсить.
        else:
            break
```